# iOS, quicktime and html5 captioned videos

Tags: ios, iphone, video, mobile-safari, quicktime

I’m using captions in video. It works well on desktop browsers and some android devices. The problem is on iOS because it overrides the video with quicktime. As far as I understand, captions in quicktime are coded into the movie.

Example: The first video on [this page](https://flowplayer.org/demos/timeline/) uses captions that aren’t viewable on an iOS device.

Is it possible to do any of the following:

1. Disable quicktime programatically?
2. Control quicktime programatically from the browser?
3. Place captions over quicktime using data from the browser?

Any other solutions to this problem are welcome.

Comment: I'm also need the same requirement. if any one know solution for this pls share your thoughts.